# Apple Documentation and Xcode header file does not fully correspond

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa

**Environment**:

XCode: *Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)*

The Apple documents referred here is come from the XCode itself, not the online document

**Description**:

From Apple documents, the relationship of **UITalbeViewController** class with others are shown in the figure below. It inherits from 1 class and conforms to 7 protocols (you will find out that it conforms to 8 protocols from [online documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller) [accessed at 18th June 2017]).

[image]

When I open the XCode header file by command click the **UITalbeVIewController** string, I got the following result (please see the figure below). It only shows out 2 protocols (UITalbeViewDelegate and UIBalbeVIewDataSource)

[image]

**Question:**

Why the header file does not show the other 5 protocols the **UITableViewController** conforms to?

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different reasons depending on the protocols.

Some protocols are adopted in an extension, and so do not appear listed in the class definition. Take the `UIStateRestoring` and `NSExtensionRequestHandling` protocols for example. You will find in the header of `UIViewController` that they are adopted by `UIViewController` in an extension (and so by inheritance are also adopted by `UITableViewController`).

Some have their adoption automatically generated by the compiler when importing Objective-C classes in Swift. As a result you will not see their adoption in the headers because the headers are just Objective-C headers rewritten in Swift. This is the case for `Equatable` and `Hashable`. In Objective-C all classes that inherit from `NSObject` have a `isEqual(_:)` method and a `hash` property and so automatically adopt the `Equatable` and `Hashable` protocols in Swift (but the protocols don't exist in Objective-C).

Some are used as markers by the compiler to implement the bridge between Swift and C or Objective-C. This is the case for the `CVarArg` protocol. You can see that this protocol is empty so could be adopted by any class or struct, but it's used to let the compiler know that classes that adopt it can be used safely with some very specific C APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your help and nice explanation